# phpMyAdmin Warning (setup)

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, localhost, osx-mountain-lion

I have problem setting up phpmyadmin on my mac. I am quite new here and I will be greatful if someone could give me a hand.

```
http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/
```

I have followed tutorial from that link and everything went fine till configuration.

In Firefox I cannot open phpmyadmin setup link, it gives me big error as from image...

While in Chrome and Safari if I try to login a few times with unexisting username and password, I can access setup. But then I get different kind of errors:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/var/folders/lt/8_h20skn5654p70bncx05d3h0000gn/T/sess_07ee21d2fa014a365d748382eaf8d2d6c6862893, O_RDWR) 
    failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that 
    the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0
```

In tutorial it says that I have to make "New server". When I click there and type my password (same as one for SQL). It cannot save the server. Just redirect me back to Basic settings from authentication.

Please help I am confused...

ScreenShot of Error:
[image: ScreenShot Error #1]

Error that I have mentioned that appear in chrome is actually when I try to login a few times with ofc unexisting username and password. Then I get access to setup with other two errors.

[image: no desc]

Other screenshots:
[image: no desc]

[image: no desc]

P.S. If you need logs I will gladly provide them, if you tell me how! Cheers.

Comment: phpMyadmin also sometimes get confused with cookies. So, you can erase all your browser history, if not needed again, and reopen the phpMyadmin page.

Comment: Yeh tried. Nothing happends. Errors remain in Chrome&Safari and FF gives that big red error.

Comment: @sikas Sure in a momment

Comment: Warning: Unknown: open(/var/folders/lt/8_h20skn5654p70bncx05d3h0000gn/T/sess_07ee21d2fa014a365d748382eaf8d2d6c6862893, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 - Needs permission. chmod

Comment: @ConnorT all right... can you tell me what to type in terminal to chmod it ?

Comment: Why aren't You using MAMP? It's a package of PHP, MySQL and Apache packed also with phpMyAdmin - all configured and set so after the installation You are ready to go. There are also packages for Win (WAMP) and Linux (LAMP).

Comment: @shadyyx , yeh... I was using XAMP as windows user, but thought not to use MAMP on mac. Instead to run integrated things and install others. :) 
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its basically saying PHP is not allowed to write to the directory that sessions are saved to.

You could do one of a few things:

Change the session save path in your `php.ini`

```
session.save_path = /tmp
```

If this is just a development machine you set it some where else like

```
session.save_path = /users/php/sessions
```

And then `chmod 777` that directory.

See this page for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Otherwise you could set a new `session.save_handler`. This is a little bit harder so I probably wouldn't go down that road.

These page will give you information on that though:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php
- [Creating custom PHP Session handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057466/creating-custom-php-session-handler)

And finally you could just allow the PHP user to access the path its trying to.

I assume you would need to do something like:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/folders/lt/8_h20skn5654p70bncx05d3h0000gn/T/
sudo chmod 777 /var/folders/lt/8_h20skn5654p70bncx05d3h0000gn/T/
```

Comment: EDIT: Indeed your last assume helped. However I hope I wont need to mkdir and chmod everytime for new setup. It removed error, made new database and I am able to access it. Thanks Petah!

Comment: For 11 hours I am available to give you bounty. Ill come back. Cheers man.

Comment: @NenaddvL glad it helped. On a typical option 1 is normally how you configure it. It seems your setup/installer just does a few odd things.

Comment: @achairapart look at your phpinfo by putting `phpinfo();` in a script or running `php -i` on the CLI. It should say what ini files it is reading.

Comment: @Petah Thanks, I actually sorted out creating a new `php.ini` file in `/etc`. I found this and other useful tips in this post: http://www.weshooper.com/osx-php-mysql

Answer (score 3):

Edit your "config.inc.php" file and add the following line:

```
$cfg['SessionSavePath'] = '/tmp';
```

Comment: I don't have config.inc.php as I cannot configurate a new database. However if I add this line into config.sample.inc.php then still nothing.