# PHP session_sava_path() to MySQL table

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I've been looking into making my own session handler for my PHP application, simply because I want to store the session data in a MySQL Memory table instead of on the local filesystem.

There are 4 main reasons for me to do this.

1. The MySQL server is local, so reading from memory will be faster.
2. Being able to list active users
3. Making an easy way for an admin to read and modify a user session, without having them logging ind and out.
4. Being able to run scripts after a session timeout, or a user "idle" variable in the session.

I can't seem to find any easy way for doing this.

I could use memcached, but it would result in doubling the session data in the memory on my server.

Does anybody know of an easy way, to force PHP at run-time, to use a MySQLi resource as session storage?

Comment: Look into PHP's function: session_set_save_handler:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057466/creating-custom-php-session-handler

Comment: The problem with settings the save handler, as people do in the PHP documentation, is that you have to use new functions for your sessions. This means I would have to change alot of code.
I'm thing there might be a module, extension or something out there, which replaces/adds functionality to the original session handler.

Comment: @Drejer: No you won't. Just use the session save-handler that comes with the memcache extension and you're done. It's a simple setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Mysql offers a memcache interface that first uses memory and can later on persitent into a real database table.

It can be simply configured via php.ini after you've create the tabels in your database server (see [here](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/152-Not-only-SQL-memcache-and-MySQL-5.6.html)):

```
; when using the "memcache" extension:
session.save_handler=memcache
; when using the "memcached" extension:
; session.save_handler=memcached

session.save_path="tcp://localhost:11211"
```

You find it outlined here with PHP examples:

- [Not only SQL - memcache and MySQL 5.6](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/152-Not-only-SQL-memcache-and-MySQL-5.6.html) (14 Apr 2011; by Johannes Schlüter)
- [MySQL, Memcache, PHP revised](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/169-MySQL,-Memcache,-PHP-revised.html) (30 Sep 2012; by Johannes Schlüter)